# CSS: Pass a variable in nth-child with angular

Tags: css, angular, sass

I want to pass a variable that comes from the model ts into a nth-child, but I don’t know how to do this.
For now my code looks like this:

ts model:

```
@Input() public limit: number
```

scss:

```
.collapsed-list {
  max-height:15rem;
  overflow: hidden;

  .expandable:nth-child(${limit}) {
     color: red;
  }
}
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround is to add a class from the template when counter === limit.

```
.max {
   color: red;
}
    
<div class="collapsed-list" *ngFor=" counter; let index ">
  <div [class]="index === limit ? 'max' : ''"
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, it works, thanks. I’ve been struggling for a while